# Commutative diagrams with TikZ: how do I compress this diagram?

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

So I am trying to do a taxonomy diagram using the `tikzcd` package. The diagram can be generated with following code (I do not how to show a picture of directly):

```
\documentclass
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=4em, cells={nodes={draw=gray}}, column sep=small]
\& \&  \text{Probability distribution inference} \arrow[dl] \arrow[dr] \& \text{Direct} \& \\
\& \text{Explicit density} \arrow[dl] \arrow[d] \& \& \text{Implicit density} \arrow[u] \arrow[d] \& \\
\text{Tractable density}\& \text{Approximate density} \arrow[d] \arrow[dr] \&  \& \text{Markov Chain} \&   \\
\& \text{Variational} \& \text{Markov Chain} \& \& \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

This goes outside the frame and there is a lot of white space in cells where I have not inserted any items. Also there is no symmetry in places where we would clearly want it. What commands can I use in order to fix this? In hindsight, `tikzcd` might not have been the optimal choice of constructing a taxonomy diagram, but I really like the esthetics of it.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Please post a complete MWE (minimal working example) instead of just a code snippet. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I tried doing this, but it does not work. @schtandard

Comment: Well, just adding `\documentclass` and `\end{document}` is not enough, of course. You need to make it a complete document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess (from "... goes outside the frame") that you use `beamer` presentation and that you looking for something like this:

[image]

With use of the `makecell` package and redefining `cells` parameters, it is possible to write multiline cells contents:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Taxonomy diagram}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1em, 
                   cells={nodes={draw=gray, semithick, 
                          font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont, 
                          align=center}}, 
                   ]
    &   &   \makecell{Probability\\ distribution\\ inference} \ar[dl] \ar[dr] 
            &   \makecell{Direct}   
                \\
    &   \makecell{Explicit\\ density} \ar[dl] \ar[d] 
        &   &   \makecell{Implicit\\ density} \arrow[u] \arrow[d] 
                \\
\makecell{Tractable\\ density}
    & \makecell{Approximate\\ density} \ar[d] \ar[dr] 
        &   &   \makecell{Markov\\ Chain} 
                \\
    &   \makecell{Variational} 
        &   \makecell{Markov\\ Chain} 
            &   
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```